# Swift iOS Which View Is On Top

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In my app I have a background task running that alerts the user when a certain event happens.  What has to happen next depends on which view is currently on top.  How can I determine this?  I thought about writing some indicator into a plist file but that seems a bit clunky especially if there's a system way of doing it.

Comment: Can we get some more information, like code you've tried? How are the views created? Are they shown in IB? etc.

Comment: You probably need to re-think your approach, your model, which this clearly is, shouldn't have anything to do with your view. http://bit.ly/1bublha

Comment: You're correct about rethinking my approach.  I need to use delegates since the event can happen on any view.  I haven't tried that approach yet but I'm sure I will be able to get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

that's how it can be done in objective c

```
if([self.navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MYController Class]])
     //then do something
```

I'm sure you cab find out the swift version easily

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible ways:

- First, you could use `NSUserDefaults` to set a Bool or String indicator. Assuming you're using Swift, try:

  `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("FirstViewOnTop", forKey:"WhatViewIsOnTop?")`
  `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`

  When you want to retrieve the value, use:

  `let indicatorString = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("WhatViewIsOnTop?")`

  You could use an if/else statement from there.
- The way I would go about doing it, though, is to subclass `UIView` and add a `z` property and add it to the init(). Then you can access it much more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect opportunity to use `NSNotificationCenter`.  Have the background task post a notification that your view controllers will listen for.  When the active viewController gets the notification, it can handle it in the way that is appropriate for that viewController.

Send the Notification from the main queue since your task is running in the background:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("SomethingWonderfulHappened", object: nil)
}
```

Receive the Notification: For each of your viewControllers that might want to act on the notification, override `viewDidAppear` to start listening for notifications, and override `viewDidDisappear` to stop listening for notifications:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleNotification:", name:"SomethingWonderfulHappened", object: nil)

}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Notification Handler: Implement one of these for each of your viewControllers.  Have each one do what is appropriate for that viewController.

```
func handleNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    //Action to take when SomethingWonderfulHappened
}
```